# Administrator cannot administer sql server reporting services

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am running SQL Server Reporting Services on SQL Server 2008 Standard and trying to get the web pages to work.

---

What do I have to do to get RS (Report Manager, Reporting Services Connection), to see me as an admin in the first place so that I can make then change my role and look at the Web Service URL properly?

---

I have Windows authentication Enabled in II7 and I have anonymous authentication disabled.

I am logged in as a local Administrator (however the pages don't seem to realize that I am an admin).

Through the tables in ReportServer db, I can tell that BUILTIN\Administrators is in there.

I have my local machine in Trusted Sites in Internet Explorer.

Using Chrome instead of IE, I get similar results. I have not tried Firefox.

Most of the help I have found online assumes that you can add your login as an administrator explicitly from the perspective of RS.  I cannot figure out how to do that because everyway I try to administer roles I cannot get to work....

At:

http://machine/ReportServer_DEPAHELIX

I get:

Reporting Services Error

The permissions granted to user 'Chris-PC\Chris' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) Get Online Help

---

SQL Server Reporting Services

At:
http://machine/Reports_DEPAHELIX/Pages/Folder.aspx
I see only Home, with Home, My Subscriptions, Help and cannot really do anything.  There are no reports there yet because when I try to deploy from BIDS, I get Error   1   The permissions granted to user 'Chris-PC\Chris' are insufficient for performing this operation.        0   0

---

At: 
http://machine/Reports_DEPAHELIX/Pages/SystemSecurity.aspx
I see 
You do not have permission to access this page.

---

And when I connect to Reporing Services through SQL Server Management Studio, I see Jobs, Security and Shared Schedules, and that's it.  I can expand Security>Roles and see 5 built in roles, however 
when I right click on a Role, the context menu has Properties grayed out.

---

What do I have to do to get RS to see me as an admin?

---

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Vista Home Premium SP1? If so, then I have the same problem, and it's because an administrative user is not necessarily in the "BUILTIN\Adminstrators" group.

Comment: Windows Vista Ultimate.  Oh okay I didn't realize that local Administrators group and BUILTIN\Administrator were different.  Your answer cleared things up for me.  So one has to run these as "THE" Administrator, not just one of the members of the Administrators group.  I went in to Local Users and enabled the Administrator account so I could login and get a Desktop as "Administrator" not just "Chris" (who is AN Administrator).  Everything is working completely as would be expected now.    Can get Properties in SQL Server that way, and the proper Report Manager web functionality. Thanks John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appreciate you have a resolution; if anyone else has this problem; MS have put a step by step guide up on msdn. "Configure a Report Server for Local Administration on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630430.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I have the same exact problem, i am running on Windows 7. I also cannot deploy to the SQL Server, if I am not logged in as Administrator (and not as a users of the Admin group.)
One thing that solved my problem is to start Internet Explorer as Administrator, even if you are logged in as a Admin users. (Right-click and select "Start as an Administrator") Same in Visual Studio in order for you to deploy. It's annoying, but it works...

Answer (score 2):

As stated by John, must be "Administrator", not just a member of Administrators group.  Trying to make more users part of BUILTIN\Administrators is not the answer.  The answer is to login initially as "Administrator" and then setup Reporting Services related groups for your system or domain then configure the roles associated with those groups using RS tools, and add the appropriate users to the specific new groups.

Comment: In Vista, Windows 7, or Server 2008, you do not necessarily have to login as the Administrator account. If you go to `All Programs` in the start menu, then you can right click on IE and select "Run as Administrator". I have confirmed this works on server 08.

I would also imagine if you had User Account Control disabled, that you would not even need to run IE as an admin.

Comment: +1 Justin, this is definitely the quickest and easiest way to do this on the Operating Systems you listed. Worked straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer after hours of searching ...

As other users suggest, you need to right-click and choose Run As Administrator.  However, on Windows 7 it seems that Internet Explorer by default does not provide current user credentials to Reporting Services. What happens then is that you get a login prompt when you try to access Reporting Services. ***If you get a login prompt, you need to adjust security settings.***

Choose Intenet Options and go to the Security tab. Click on Trusted sites. Either drag the security slider to low security or click on Custom level. If you click on Custom level, go to the User Authentication/Logon option and choose "Automatic logon with current name and password".

Original post here for reference:
http://blogical.se/blogs/jahlen/archive/2009/10/02/setting-up-sql-server-reporting-services-on-windows-7-vista-or-windows-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server 2008 does not recognize Windows administrators as database sysadmins.  You have to add the Windows administrator group to the Sql sysadmins role.

You can add the group like this:

1. Open Sql Server Management Studio
2. Open Security -> Logins, and create a login for the Administrators group
3. Open Security -> Server Roles, and add the login to the syadmin role

During installation, setup will offer to make the current user a database administrator.  If you accept that, the current windows user will be added to the database sysadmin group.  If you installed Sql Server as "Administrator", that explains why only the "Administrator" account was able to configure your Reporting server.

If you had installed Sql Server as "YourDomain\YourAccount", that account would have added to the sysadmin role instead.  So there's nothing special about "The" administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Andomar and I agree with everything that you said - that is all true, however that was not my particular problem.  In my case my current user "Chris" was also a SQL Server Administrator.  The "Administrator" account was NOT a SQL Server Administrator, however WAS able to perform the actions that I was trying to take with the Reporting Services.

Comment: Interesting... that must be yet another security system.  Did you try with Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -> Configuration Tools -> Reporting Services Configuration Manager?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the BUILTIN\Administrators account is not treated correctly for permissions within SSRS, if you create a new group Eg SSRS_Administrators and add all your admin users to this group and define SSRS_Administrators as a content manager within report manager all is good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a local admin, run c:\program files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe as administrator (right-click, run as administrator).  This open the SSRS Report Manager and you can do what's needed.