# Can not access Report Manager URL in Reporting Services Configuration Manager

Tags: ssrs-2008

I've installed the SQl Server 2008 Reporting services on my PC but when I try to access the Report Manager URL

```
(http://localhost/Reports)
```

I first get prompted to log on, and then after several attempts I end up at a blank screen.

I don't know if it is permissions, or even something as basic as the set up is not complete.

The best link I've found so far has been this page:
http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/reportserver-permissions-granted-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation-rsaccessdenied

and I've followed the steps as far as step 4. I don't get re-directed to

```
http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx.
```

Typing the URL in manually gives a blank page in IE, but I get an xml parsing error with Firefox.

Any advice and help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Some additional information. When using Business Intelligence Design Studio I can deploy data sources and reports and the output window reports a success.

More info:
I log onto my machine as an Administrator.
I've installed MS Sql Server 2008 RS (Standard)

I've hit a dead end with this. Can't get any further. Nearly everything I've seen suggests the problem is to do with not being an administrator but I am.

Comment: This link on StackOverflow describes the same problem I have. But the solutions it suggests haven't yet worked for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930947/administrator-cannot-administer-sql-server-reporting-services

That said I'd say if others have similar problems then the above link seems the best place to start.

Comment: I should clarify that I'd installed Reporting Services on my local machine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not all administrators are created equal. I've recently got a new PC and set up an 'administrator' account.

This article explains what I needed to do to enable the real 'admin'. Once he was there, my previous account that apparently was an 'administrator' reverted to being an standard user, and the conundrum was solved.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/7f477018-aa14-4db0-8989-ce763b122a2a

The comment that really helped me was the one by 'dana_working'. I've re-produced it in full in case the article is deleted.

```
Hi,

I don't know if the OP solved his issue or not, but I had the same problem and 
after banging my head against my desk for two days thought I would share what 
worked for me.
One caveat - I did try a number of things before hitting on what worked for me, 
and there may be something else I did along the way that was also necessary 
(though not sufficient).  I did not make any registry or direct .config changes:

System setup:  Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium; AMD processor; SQL Server Express 2008 R2;   
just running this stuff on my machine for development purposes.

Symptoms:  Could not get the URLs in Report Services Configuration Manager to work, 
even though it was all working fine on a Vista system I set up a few months ago.  
I have administrator priveleges.  I tried opening IE as administrator, authorizing 
my login in various ways through the configuration manager but just could not get in.    
It is not possible, btw, to manage the report server grough SSMS in the Express 
version.  You need to find a way into Report Manager with the URL.

Crux/Solution:  Basically, my administrator account was not THE administrator 
account for the computer; THE administrator (which is hidden) is different than 
having administrator rights.  So the following steps worked to fix the issue 
for me:

I authorized the "hidden Administrator" account.  In Home Premium edition I did 
this by opening a command prompt "as administrator" and entering net user 
administrator /active:yes

From what I've read, this can be done through control panel with higher 
versions of Windows 7.

Log off and voila there is another user now besides yourself.  
Logon now as Administrator

Open IE "as administrator" and go to http://servername/Reports_SQLEXPRESS url.  
I was able to log in at this point.

Once in Report Manager, I authorized my regular Windows account with all 
privileges.  I did this in two locations - maybe someone can explain the 
difference between the two.

Click upper right for "Site Settings"; "Security"; Add yourself as New 
Role as a Site Administrator - you can do this following the steps outlined 
in reply Jin Chen above.

I also found I needed to go back to "Home"; "Folder Settings"; Add yourself 
as New Role with Content Manager as outlined above by MustafaH.
Apply, save, etc.; log out; go back to your regular logon; 
open IE "as administrator" (not sure if that's necessary but I did it anyway) 
and go to the URL, log on with your id, saving credentials.

You now can get into Report Manager just opening IE and going to the URL's;  
Deployment from Bus Intelligence Studio works now too.

Good luck!!
```

Comment: This worked for me. Remove the "int." from Daniel's url or you'll get a certificate error.  However the post by Dana_Working was on the money.  I did have an extra step, too, that of adding a password to my Administrator account, otherwise you cannot log on to the ReportManager page (with a blank password).  Modify that and then you can log in, then add your main account to the Site Security and under the Folder Properties as a Content Manager.  Why on earth is such a routine task made so difficult?  Microsoft?

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for mentioning the problems with the link. I've edited my post and updated it now. Glad this helped you.

Comment: Kudos to answerer for detailing the answer that worked and the caveats around it.  This worked for me.  Let me add that this is still a problem with SSRS in SQL Server 2016 ctp 2.  I believe it is due to running SSRS on a workgroup rather than domain-joined machine; on the former, *any* member of BUILTIN/Administrators works without fuss, but on workgroup, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new local user on the server and add it to the Administrators group.

Then, browse to the report manager URL and when you are prompted for credentials, enter the credentials you used for the new local user.

This should allow you to access the report manager. Worked for me!

Comment: I was installing Reporting Services on my local machine so I thought my account was already an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue earlier and I too was stuck. I am not an expert but just a beginner to SSRS but thought to share my exp. here if it can help someone. The issue in my case was I have not set the permission for the specific login to Hom Page (ROOT) causing the login to end up giving blank page. Giving the rights to reports and sub directories will not work when you dont provide the access to the login from where these reports are supposed to be called.

check permissions in your homepage of Reportserver URL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I hope it helps someone. This wouldn't have solved the problem I had though. That was down to the initial set up on my machine.